# Best way to control engine cooling?

Tags: cooling-system

Should I control engine temp with a thermostat or with a cooling fan temp sensor for on/off of cooling fan?
I am installing a Tri cross flow alum radiator with full alum shroud and a special 16 inch high flow (2500 CFM electric fan) with temp probe settings of
on at 195 degrees and off at 170. I think this will regulate engine temps
even in stop/go hot weather and with use of A/C. My main question is should
I also use a thermostat in the cooling system if Yes then why??

Comment: IMO, you'll need both. I think it depends on the application and what you are trying to do. You may want to flesh out your question with more detail as to what you are trying to fix or accomplish.

Comment: It's not often that you get to choose something like this. Cars come with cooling systems obviously. You definitely can't just bypass your thermostat.. Can you please elaborate on your request?